# when running test class, encountering runAs() issues with user having insufficient access to upload resume

Tags: files, contentversion, dmlexception, fileupload, insufficient-privileges

I am encountering an issue with running my test class as a made-up user. It seems like I have insufficient access to uploading files onto the org, anyone would be able to point me in the right direction?
The profile has a Customer Portal license
I already tried enabling the Select Files from Salesforce on the profile system permissions
I already tried allowing guest access to upload files

[image: error log]

Comment: are you using criteria-based sharing to grant access to the Customer Portal user (in PROD)? Criter-based sharing isn't honored in apex testmethods. There are workarounds

Comment: I actually fixed it, I was had another id that was hardcoded on the main class, just had to pass in a parameter to make sure that the id gets properly changed on the main function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple types of error there.

`DUPLICATE_VALUE` is an error on inserting a Hierarchy Custom Setting that already exists.

`INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` is an error that can be generated by a myriad of different issues. In this case, my first guess is that the running user does not have access to the record to which you are seeking to attach the file.

Comment: Hi David,

Concerning the insufficient ability to attach the file, do you know what I could do to fix this, I tried the things mentioned above but no luck with allowing that user to attach the file.

Comment: Without more detail on the scenario, I have no idea. You should look closely at record-level access in your test setup for the record to which you are trying to attach the file.

Comment: I actually fixed it, I was had another id that was hardcoded on the main class, just had to pass in a parameter to make sure that the id gets properly changed on the main function too.